# Angular2: Alternative when two 'roots' are needed?

Tags: angular

I am trying to teach myself angular2. I'm writing a simple app with a layout that many sites have: Header (e.g. for search and logo) and main body for content.

My problem is as follows: For instance if you load facebook, you first see the rough page layout (empty divs and css), and asynchronously content is loaded in place. That's nice, you wait a bit, but at least you see what's happening.

Imagine now my (facebook-like) setup. If I want to have the same. You'd say that you put in your main html page the divs with the css. And in the div load the respective components (app).

But as far as I learned, in ng2, you can *only bootstrap a single root*. How then to load the separate header components and main view components?

Ok, you can import them and put the divs into your root template, and just load the app with the page layout. But that presents the problem that the user will see a blanc page (or sees "loading...") until the app loads, which I find visually not very appealing.

How would one go around this?

Answer (score 4):

The Prevention of "Flash of Unstyled Content" FOUC, is something you will come across unless you load your application from the server first. If you have a stack available to support it, should look into [angular-universal](https://github.com/alexpods/angular2-universal-starter) which will allow your server to compute you app and serve up the HTML already compiled. However is just one of many ways to prevent the FOUC.

Comment: Also a static compiler is planned (parts are already included in beta.16 AFAIK) where lots expensive dynamic code is replaced by more efficient static code, which shortens the time Angular needs to initialize itself after JS,  HTML, and CSS loading was completed, until Angular actually shows something on the screen.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your answer. You say there are many ways to prevent FOUC, one you named which is to pre-compile on the server. If I would like to keep the compilation in the client's browser, could you please specify what option in such case I have? (Given that I work with ng2.) The problem in that case is that I have to have a single root component. Because of that, my app only becomes visible after all child components load. Is there an option to avoid this latency?